# How to hide file inspection in project tree?

Tags: pycharm

There are tons and tons of options, and I cant find how to hide this:

[image: file inspection in project tree]

I just want the *"classical" display* list, I dont want to see what's in (I dont see a case where it would be faster than CTRL-click on the thing I'm looking for actually...):

[image: here's what I want!]

Where is that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image].

I think "Show Members" is what you are looking for. Uncheck it!